# Does using multiple HX711 amplifiers change the supply voltage of an Arduino?

Tags: sensors, arduino-nano, voltage, op-amp

I’m creating essentially a load cell using an Arduino Nano and an HX711 amplifier. However, I want to have two HX711 amplifiers running off the same Arduino. Will that change the supply voltage since I’m using two (ex. Does it change from 5V to 2.5V)? I need an accurate supply voltage for the Wheatstone bridge equations to determine strain from the strain gauge readings, but I’m unsure what adding another amplifier will do to the supply voltage.

Comment: how are you connecting them?

Comment: Sorry - should have specified that. They all share a single clock line and use different data lines. I’m using the HX711 multi library.

Comment: your question is all about the supply voltage, but you did not say anything about any connections to the power supply

Comment: Power supply module connected to a 9V battery, on the breadboard with the Arduino nano.

Comment: It sounds like you want to power the HX711's to the 5V line on the Arduino. As long as you don't exceed the current limits on the Arduino's voltage regulator, that should be fine. (connect each to 5V and to ground. Don't try to run them in series.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will that change the supply voltage

No. Components and circuits connected in parallel add together their current requirements, but the voltage stays the same.